# How to determine by an argument of symmetry the following integral equation?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I'm stuck with this exercise... I know that the equality holds...  I tried to do some changes with cylindrical and spherical coordinates but I dont get it, and I don't know how to apply the argument of symmetry, I've been reading Marsden Tromba, Chapter 6 they have some exercises using symmetry, but they didn't help me... any help or hint would be appreciated.. thank you so much!

Determine if using a symmetry argument the next equality holds:

$$\displaystyle\int_{0}^1\int_{-2}^2\int_{1}^2 z^{-1}xye^{e^{x^2}}(y^2+1)^{-3}2^{y^4x^6+x^8y^7+5}dydxdz=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}cos^4(t)sin(t)dt$$

Comment: Doesn't the $z$ integral diverge? The integrand has just $z^{-1}$ integrated over $[0,1]$, giving $\int_0^1\frac1z\mathrm dz=[\ln z]_0^1\to\infty$

Comment: yes, that is, yes, if u integrate $\dfrac{1}{z}$ diverges...

Comment: In that case, it can't be equal to the RHS, since the RHS is convergent.

Comment: Thank you!, then the equality doesn't holds....

Comment: Yes, correct. ${}$